# How to add graph x axis labels in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

Its important to me that these labels have a tightly bound relationship with their corresponding bars.  I wouldn't want to create a view for the chart bars, and then another view that holds the x labels and then try to make sure they line up.  That would generate out of sync errors.  Using UIKit, I would probably create a 3 way view relationship where the x labels are centered to their corresponding bars, and the bars bottom anchors are equal to the bottom anchor of the chart.  I have no idea how to do this in SwiftUI.

Comment: you should have your DataModel contains x potisions to control each bar and each label in x,y coordinator. then can use ZStack + GeometryReader to implement

Comment: @QuangHà  Sounds good to me. Can you throw it into an answer?